# OpenID Consumer error

Tags: openid

During integration Zend OpenID Server into MVC I have problem with Consumers answer (at Livejournal). It says:

> "naive_verify_failed_return: Provider says signature is invalid".

Does anyone have any ideas why it can appears? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the consumer is running in stateless mode and the OP failed to verify the signature. Assuming a correctly-implemented OP and no data corruption, this shouldn't happen. These days the most common reason for this to happen is a long-standing bug in `Net::OpenID::Consumer` that causes it to send a malformed signature verification request to a OpenID 2.0 OP.

I've just pushed a fix for this to CPAN in `Net-OpenID-Consumer 1.030099_003` and it will be in a stable release soon. In the meantime you workaround this by implementing an association cache so that stateless mode is avoided. See this thread for more details:

http://groups.google.com/group/openid-perl/browse_thread/thread/6f28a022cce5bcdd